# How to search by different parameters with Django REST API?

Tags: python, django, search, filter

Suppose I'm developing a backend for an application that will have products or something, and that application will communicate with the server through REST API.

Each product will have multiple fields like title, description, price, rating...

What are some of the good ways for filtering by multiple fields?

---

Example:

Search string: gaming laptop

price: from 400$ to 1000$

rating: more than 3 stars

...

---

I was planning to have a single string that confirms pre-defined rules for searching, taking it, parse it, and returning the result.

So, the URL would look something like this: `www.foo.com/products/search/contains=laptop&min_price=400&max_price=1000&min_stars=3`.

these filters are optional.

Not sure if taking a single string then parsing it is the best way.

Comment: There are simply too many ways to do this. Querystrings are one, but there can be anything, including data in POST. Just do one and make sure it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this by adding queries with Q function like this `query = Q(price=myPrice)`, then lets suppose in a certain condition you want to add another "and" condition to it

```
if conditional_variable:
    query =& Q(name=productName)
```

(same thing applies for or statements) and than to apply it you can do it like this `products = Products.objects.filter(query)`, in the other hand to make conditions like greater than or less than you can do it like this

```
Products.objects.filter(product_price__lte=1000)
```

this means less than or equal

You have lt -> less than, gt-> greater than, gte-> greater than or equal.
Using those you can combine than however you want and make multiple queries with or(we use | for or).

In my opinion, for complex queries do not filter with get parameters in url with get, but try to do them like above in a post where it returns what you want.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!